# How to derive: $\sin(x-a)\sin(x+a) = \sin^2(x) - \sin^2(a)?$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals, derivation-of-formulae, derivations

I was looking at the solution of

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{\sin(x−a)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x+a)}}dx.$$

Where the formula,
$$\sin(x-a)\sin(x+a) = \sin^2x - \sin^2a = \cos^2 a - \cos^2 x$$
is used, I want to know how it was derived as I couldn't find it on the net.

Comment: Given that you are integrating, you should be familiar with the angle addition formula for trigonometric functions.  I would suggest that you review those.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner the equality as written is true. It is a surprising and amusing result I stumbled on a few years back, because it does look the an erroneous difference of squares.

Comment: Your last equality is incorrect. $$\sin^2x-\sin^2a=\cos^2a-\cos^2 x.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}\sin(x-a)\sin(x+a) &=\frac{\cos(2a)-\cos(2x)}2=\frac{1-2\sin^2a-(1-2\sin^2x)}2= \sin^2x - \sin^2a\end{align}$

Comment: $$\sin A\sin B=\frac{\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)}2$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sin(x-a)\sin(x+a)&=(\sin x\cos a-\cos x\sin a)(\sin x\cos a+\cos x\sin a) \\
&=\sin^2x\cos^2 a-\cos^2 x\sin^2 a \\
&=\sin^2x(1-\sin^2a)-(1-\sin^2 x)\sin^2 a \\
&=\sin^2 x-\sin^2 a
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks , also (1-cos²x)cos²a - cos²x(1-cos²a) = cos²a - cos²x